# Microsoft Excel or openoffice - formula that search entire row for specific data (number) and if found copy data from adjacent cell to the right

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have one row of cells with 20 columns, I want to write a formula that searches entire row for number 38 (only exact matches) and if it finds it, copy the data from adjacent cell to the right. How should I write this formula ?

Comment: By "match case" i mean that the cell only contains that number, no other text or numbers, and no, there can't be more instances of 38.

Comment: By the way i have researched this for hours.. tried with VLOOKUP many tutorials but have found nothing that works..

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=INDEX(1:1,,MATCH(38,1:1,0)+1)
```

by the way Match case is for Large or sMall letters, "Match entire cell contents" is a different option in Find/Replace.

Restrict the column range to exclude the column in which you place the formulae.

Comment: it have returned an error, i am using openoffice but i guess the formula have to be same, it gaves me error 502: Invalid argument  A function argument has an invalid value, e.g. a negative number for the root function. ?

Comment: Thank you @pnuts for your great help, the solution was your formula little modified and added the OFFSET function

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
after few hours work and little help of this community except pnuts the result that works in Openoffice is:

> =OFFSET(INDEX(A1:G1;;MATCH(38;A1:G1;0));0;1)

Dont know why the +1 in index function as pnuts wrote did not work, but OFFSET function did.